# KnockoutJS pseudobinding failing in IE8

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, internet-explorer-8

The following fails in IE8, but works in real browsers

```
<div data-bind="with: currentItem, visible: currentItemState() === 'view'">

    <!-- ko if: resource().versions().length -->
    <!-- ko with: resource().versions()[0] -->

    <div style="margin-top: 15px;" data-bind="visible: error()">
         .....

    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
```

Basically I'm getting `property 'error' is null or undefined` which means the `with` (and `if`) bindings aren't working properly.  This is probably because IE8 is stripping the comments out, which I've seen it do in other contexts, like within a `<select>` node, but I've never seen it do that in a place like this.

Is there a good way to fix this (without working around the problem by changing my html structure)?

Comment: They are working properly by themselves, but I think the problem is you are nesting two containerless bindings within each other, right?

Comment: @PWKad - that should be fine - and it is fine, in normal browsers like Chrome.

Comment: Why not just wrap the with within a div so IE8 is happy?

Comment: @PWKad - that's plan B; I want to see if there's a cleaner solution.  Besides, we probably won't support IE8 forever...at least I hope not.

Comment: Most of the time when I have come across this, it is not down to knockout but HTML.  Things like not closing tags off properly such as having a self closing `<label />` that busted it

Comment: @Thewads - you know, thinking about it, that's almost certainly the issue.  We're extremely cavalier about things like that.  Can you post that as an answer so I can throw you an upvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time when I have come across this, it is not down to knockout but HTML. Things like not closing tags off properly such as having a self closing `<label />` that busted it.

IE8 is very particular about this stuff. I had one place where it didn't render the bottom half of a `<!-- ko if -->` because of the lable issue

Comment: I can't perfectly verify this (already worked around it, and need to move on), but this is by far the most likely cause of the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the second containerless binding within an empty div so that it is parsed correctly in all browsers

```
<div data-bind="with: currentItem, visible: currentItemState() === 'view'">
    <!-- ko if: resource().versions().length -->
        <div>
        <!-- ko with: resource().versions()[0] -->
            <div style="margin-top: 15px;" data-bind="visible: error()">
        <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a proper way to fix this, but it turns out knockout's `with` binding is intelligent enough to not render the nodes at all if the with*ed* value is undefined.  So replacing *both* of those pseudo bindings with just

```
<div data-bind="with: resource().versions()[0]">
```

appears to fix the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that resource() has a property versions() with a value in the first slot when the DOM is ready?

Comment: @PWKad - verions is an array that always exists.  If it's empty, then that expression will return undefined, which KO will deal with appropriately by not rendering the nodes.

Comment: That depends - if you have a resource() but that resource does not yet have a versions() property, (ie you are creating that property on the return of an AJAX call or something) then your binding will break.  To test it you can go back to the if: binding and use $data.resource().versions()[0]

Comment: @PWKad - the way our knockout mapper is set up, a resource will always, from the moment it's created, have a versions array.  The only way the binding could break is if someone maliciously typed `delete currentItem().versions`